# Python Pandas DataFrame Describe Gives Wrong Results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While I was looking at the results of the `describe()` method, I realized something very strange. Data is the House Price data from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) . Below, you can see the code and the result for "Condition2" feature:

```
train.groupby(train["Condition2"].fillna('None'))["SalePrice"].describe()
```

On the other hand, when I look at data in Excel, the quantiles do not match.
So, while 33% of data points 85K SalePrice, how can 25% of data points be 95.5K SalePrice? It is really weird, or may be I'm missing something. Could anybody explain this?

[image: excel]

[image: Python Result]

Answer (score 0):

Quantiles seek to divide the data into four equal groups so the value of the 25% quantile isn't going to be the value of the 25% of your data with small sample sizes like this where `n=6`. There are different methods of calculating [quantile values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile). Describe uses the `linear` method described in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) as

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

If you switch to the `lower` method it produces different results.

```py
>>> feedr = train_df[train_df.Condition2 == 'Feedr']
>>> feedr.SalePrice.quantile(.50)
127500.0
>>> feedr.SalePrice.quantile(.50, interpolation='lower')
127000
>>> feedr.SalePrice.quantile(.25, interpolation='lower')
85000
>>> feedr.SalePrice.quantile(.25)
95500.0
```